# WinAPI Create a new Desktop for currently logged on user within the Service

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible for a Service, running as Local System Account, to create new desktop for currently logged on user and then launch a process there?

Comment: Not directly, no. But it can enumerate logged in user sessions (there may be more than one), launch a process in the desired user's session, then that process can create a new desktop and launch another process on it